# Grafana : skipDataQuery in plugin.json

Tags: grafana

I am learning how to write grafana plugins.
This is my first plugin (file module.tsx) that works:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { PanelProps, PanelPlugin } from '@grafana/data';

export class MyPanel extends PureComponent<PanelProps> {
  render() {
    return (
            <h1 className="center-vh">My First Panel</h1>
        );
    }
}
export const plugin = new PanelPlugin(MyPanel);
```

How could I remove the query tab in the panel editor ?
I add `"skipDataQuery": true,` in the *plugin.json* file but it does not work. I use Grafana v6.6.0 (5c11bbdfb4)
Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy answer.

`"skipDataQuery": true,` is correct. But grafana server must be restarted.

Compilation with `npm run watch` is not sufficient.